# Angular configure websocket url for nginx reverse proxy

Tags: angular, nginx, websocket

I've an Angular app, which is deployed to a K8S cluster and served by NGINX. I want to use a reverse proxy, to access the multiple backend deployments. For REST-calls, I've figured out how to manage this. Next topic is making this work for Websocket connections as well. I think my wss://.... calls are not being picked up by NGINX and are therefore not proxied to the correct backend. Please advice.

Angular code for creating Websocket conncetion:

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8080/ws/chat/user');
```

nginx.conf:

```
....
location ^~ /ws {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
            proxy_pass http://backendurl:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
....
```